# How to build a series of 32 bit words from block of text at compile-time

Tags: string, macros, c-strings, words, compile-time

C newbie here - I'm working with an embedded device and have an interest in transmitting a 'page' of ASCII characters over a particular protocol.

This protocol mandates transmitting 2 characters (in particular bit positions) of a 32 bit word. The rest of the bits in the word are being used for other purposes.

Instead of defining a page such as

```
MY_PAGE {
{ WHATEVER, 'H', 'E', BAR} // word 1
{ WHATEVER, 'L', 'L', BAR} //word 2
{ WHATEVER, 'O', NUL, BAR} // word 3
}
```

For clarity, I would like to simply specify "Hello" and let a macro handle the assembly of data words to make that happen. Is it more hassle than it's worth?

For a run time solution I would just parse a string literal and build something in memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a scripting language to generate the data at compile time. Pick your choice but python is ideal for this sort of thing:

```py
sourcefile = open ("page.src")
generatedfile = open("page.out", "w")

# Do whatever processing you need to generate
# code from your source data that will be read by the c-compiler eg

dat = sourcefile.read(2)
generatedfile.write("{FOO, %s, %s, BAR}" %(dat[0], dat[1]))
#etc
```

Now include the generated file in your c source

```c
#include "page.out"
```

To keep your script file simpler, make sure any code that can be contained in the C file is contained in the C file, and not in the generated file, for example:

```c
struct _page pagedata = {
#include "page.out"
};
```

As a real example, I've done this in the past like so

```c
const char * fpga_data = {
#include "comma_separated_byte_values.inc"
};
```

If you are using a make file, tell it that page.out depends on page.src and on your python script, and that your object file depends on page.out:

```
page.out: page.src processpage.py
    python processpage.py

main.o: main.c page.out
    $cc main.c
```

Comment: interesting! never thought about using python or anything outside of the pre-processor really... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a job for a runtime function than a macro to be honest.  You can have the various strings & constants and other things and assemble them on the way out.  That also decouples your storage from your transmission which don't have to be the same thing at all, and probably should not.

Comment: I generally agree, although I based my answer on the assumption there was a reason that the OP needed to do this at compile time. For example perhaps the system has a very small footprint?